# How can I enable core dump?

Tags: kernel, configuration

I've edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` and change the first line to

```
#<domain> #<type> #<item> #<value>
*         soft    core    unlimited
```

but the `vmware.log` of VMware Workstation still says:

```
No core dump taken. The core dump size limit is zero.
```

Is there any other setting I should modify? Thanks.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit, 2.6.38-generic.

Comment: What ulimit -a says? And syslog report something? Have you logged in again after editing the file? I would also try hard core.

Comment: Thank you, enzotib. The 'ulimit -a' says the 'core file size (blocks, -c) 0'. So I guess the my modification in the limits.conf didn't work. I tried hard core (by changing the <type> from 'soft' to 'hard'), but it didn't work either. the core file size still be 0.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you are running the crashing process as root. If that is the case, change the domain from '*' to 'root'. The limit.conf lines that contain the wildcard (a.k.a. '*') does not affect the 'root' account.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` sets the limits, not the defaults. To actually use it you have to run `ulimit -c unlimited` in the shell you are using.

As with any shell commands to be run in every shell, this can be put in, for example, `~/.bashrc` (per user) or `/etc/bash.bashrc` (all users).